# Data table is showing no data available in table using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable

When I was trying to show data table in angular js. It shows no data available in table but there are 4 records in table. See screenshot below.

[image]

Here's what I did.

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { UserModel }         from './user-model';
import { UserService }       from './user.service';
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'user-page',
  template: require('./user.component.html'),
  providers: [ UserService ]
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any;
  errorMessage: string;

 constructor(private userService:UserService){ }

 ngOnInit() { 
  this.getUsers();
 }

 getUsers() {  
 this.userService.getUsers()
                 .subscribe(
                   users => {this.data = users; 
                              $(function(){
                               $("#user-table").DataTable();
                              });
                            },
                   error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }              from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response }          from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { UserModel } from './user-model';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
      private usersUrl = 'http://localhost/larang/public/api/users';  
constructor (private http: Http) {}

getUsers(): Observable<UserModel[]> { 
 return this.http.get(this.usersUrl)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
}


private extractData(res: Response) { 
  let body = res.json();

  return body.data || { };
}

private handleError (error: Response | any) { console.log(error);

 let errMsg: string;
 if (error instanceof Response) {
  const body = error.json() || '';
  const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
  errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
 } else {
   errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
 }
console.error(errMsg);
return Observable.throw(errMsg);
 }
}
```

**user.component.html**

```
<table id="user-table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
 <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Added On</th>
      </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
         <td>{{item.name}}</td>
         <td>{{item.email}}</td>
         <td>{{item.added}}</td>
       </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**this.data** looks like this

```
[
 {"name":"John Doe","email":"john.doe@gmail.com","added":"2017-04-26"},
 {"name":"Ramkishan","email":"Ramkishan@gmail.com","added":"2017-04-26"},
 {"name":"Jason Bourne","email":"jason@gmail.com","added":"2017-04-26"},
 {"name":"RK","email":"ramkishan.suthar@ranosys.com","added":"2017-04-26"}
]
```

What I am doing wrong please help. It will be very helpful for newbies in Angular JS like me.

Comment: post how your data look like

Comment: yes 2 mins @Sajeetharan

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: it shows 4 rows in the table right?

Comment: yes @Sajeetharan and sorry for late replay

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: data table is showing no data found but there are four rows and sorting , searching also not working.

Comment: Make sure you got data in getUsers() method on your user.componenet.ts file ? 
try in console.log(this.data) on subscribe() method of getUser service section on user.componenet.ts file

Comment: Yes, I am getting data correctly in this.data @AshishKadam

Comment: Try datatable initialize on ngOnInit() method not in getUsers() method at user.componenet.ts file

Comment: I tried this too but didn't get success

Comment: Which Angular version you use ?

Comment: angular version 2.0

Comment: Hey @RamkishanSuthar Please mark one of the below answer as Accepted if it solves your problem. It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your **user.component.ts**, declare your data var empty to initialize it. I don't know why but I had the same problem when I refresh the page. I think the data is lost so you need to initialize it. Maybe datatable needs to know there is an Array and after you fill it it's working.

```
    ngOnInit(){
        this.data = [];
        this.getUsers();
    }
```

I WAS WRONG

You have to rerender the datatable because if you rerender the initialisation throw an error, that's why you have the message saying "no data available" despite you have in the table.

UPDATE

In your component, declare this variable:

```
  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  dtElement: DataTableDirective;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

after you pull your data from whatever service you have:

```
this.officeSrv.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('----> office service : get all data', data);
  this.offices = data.offices;

  // ADD THIS
  this.dtTrigger.next();

}, (err) => {
  console.log('-----> err', err);
})
```

If you have modification to make modification directly in the same datatable without changing the page create and call this function

```
rerender(): void {
 this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
   // Destroy the table first
   dtInstance.destroy();
   // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
   this.dtTrigger.next();
 });
}
```

Use this library in your component:

```
    import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';
```

In your app module:

```
    import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
```

And declare this :

```
    imports: [
           ...,
           DataTablesModule
```

And finally for your templating (HTML):

```
   <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0"
      width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nom</th>
          <th>Adresse</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let office of offices">
          <td>{{office.name}}</td>
          <td>{{office.adress}}</td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Action</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-info dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="update(office._id)">Mettre à jour</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="delete(office._id)">Supprimer</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Hope that's help

src : https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender

Answer (score 19):

So in my case DataTables are getting activated before I got the response from the server.
I just added *ngIf for my table and it worked for me. Like below.

```
<table *ngIf="dataService.users" datatable="ng" [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
```

Comment: it is working perfectly fine with the if condition, thanks bro

Answer (score 7):

Added Time out for solve your problem.

```
 setTimeout(function () {
  $(function () {
    $('#user-table').DataTable();
  });
}, 3000);
```

refer this video link I found on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78X8ZRU9Hy8

Comment: It easy and working solution. It works for me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a Timeout function is a bad practice. As you are using angular, the best way to solve this is by using `change detection`.

First create this instance by adding it in the constructor like this,

`...
constructor(private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { } 
...` 
in the component where you want to use datatables.

Now use the `detectChanges` function so that angular waits till something is changed(in your case, till the table is generated properly)

```
ngOnInit() { 
  ... 
   this.chRef.detectChanges();
   const table: any = $('table');
   this.dataTable = table.DataTable(); 
  ...
 }
```

So that one line `this.chRef.detectChanges()` really fixes the issue.

Comment: this is not working globally on the page.if search filters apply and submitsearch button, alignment issue comes and cell format losed occur. showing "no data available in table" on bottom of datatable. it solved putting following code on search service data. please let me know if anyother way to solve dynamic data binding without datatable destroy. I am using bootstrap & jquery datatable.Angular version is 7. $('#example').DataTable().destroy(); this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); $('#example').DataTable();

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced similar and this is how I solved mine. Am putting it out here so that in case I forget in the future, I can find it and probably help others who stumble upon this.

```
<table *ngIf="userList.length" datatable class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered mb-5">
```

I didnt like the other solutions because I was using similar in my older projects and sometimes it disturbs the user experience when recreating the table on data refresh and stuffs like that but this solved it and working fine.
The issue I believe was a time lapse between the initialization and when the server return data to the datatable.

Comment: By far the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. add this code on the constructor:

   ```
   private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
   ```
2. On the`user.component.ts -> getUsers()`, you can add a complete function:

   ```
   this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
       this.data = users;
   },
   error => { this.errorMessage = <any>error },
   () => {
       //Complete
       this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
       const table: any = $("#user-table").DataTable();
       this.dataTable = table.DataTable();
   });
   ```

Comment: if search filters apply and submitsearch button, alignment issue comes and cell format losed.showing "no data available in table" on botom of datatable. it solved putting following code on search service data. please let me know if anyother way to solve dynamic datal binding without datatable destroy. I am using bootstrap & jquery datatable.Angular version is 7.
   $('#example').DataTable().destroy();  
     this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    $('#example').DataTable();

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because the table gets rendered before you get your data.

Although it is not a proper solution but adding a timeout solves this.

To your **datatable** add this  `*ngIf="showContent"`:

```
  <table datatable="ng" *ngIf="showContent" [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover table-bordered">
```

and then in your component .ts file add this to  `ngOnInit()`

```
setTimeout(()=>this.showContent=true, 250);
```

also declare the dummy variable `showContent`.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your issue you have to add a length check condition
this will solve your problem.  use this in your tbody

```
 <tbody  *ngIf="mainData.length">
         <tr *ngFor="let group of mainData; let i = index">
                <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                <td><img class="img-thumbnail " style="width: 100px;" src="{{imgUrl}}{{group.cat_image}}"/></td>
                <td>{{group.cat_name}}</td>
               <td>{{group.cat_slug}}</td>
               <td>   <ul *ngFor="let item of mainData"><li  *ngIf="group.cat_id==item.parent && item.cat_id != group.cat_id" class="d-block"><i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i> {{item.cat_name}}</li></ul></td>
               <td>{{group.created_on}}</td>
               <td>{{group.updated_on}}</td>
               <td>
            

                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2" style="margin-right: 10px;"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-2"><i class="bi bi-trash3"></i></a>
            </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Answer (score -2):

According to the documentation [here](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way), add the following `css` to your `styles.css`

```
/*
server-side-angular-way.component.css
 */
.no-data-available {
  text-align: center;
}

/*
   src/styles.css (i.e. your global style)
*/
.dataTables_empty {
  display: none;
}
```

This will not show 'No Data' when you have data.