# Data table still showing No data even if data is filled

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, angular6

I am populating data to a table and even if there are more than 10+ rows, it still shows

> No data available in the table

I tried different solutions offered in the stack but none worked.

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38174/no-data-available-in-table-still-appears-after-rows-are-loaded-data-disappears-on-column-sorted

[Data table is showing no data available in table using Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44940021/data-table-is-showing-no-data-available-in-table-using-angular)

My code is available below, any help would be appreciated.

```js
    this.detailsService.getJobDetails(this.jobId).subscribe(data => {
      this.assetsList = data;
      if (this.jobDetails.status === "Queued") {
        this.jobRunning = true;
        this.jobExpired = false;
      } else {
        this.jobRunning = false;
        this.jobExpired = true;
      }

      this.startTime = this.timeStamptoTime(this.jobDetails.startTime);
      this.endTime = this.timeStamptoTime(this.jobDetails.endTime);
    });
```

```html
              <table id="user-table" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Asset Id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Updated</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let item of assetsList">
                    <td class="ellipsis" title="item.id">{{ item.id }}</td>
                    <td class="ellipsis-name">{{ item.title }}</td>
                    <td [ngStyle]="{ color: colorStatus }">
                      {{ item.status }}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ timeStamptoDateTime(item.startTime) }}</td>
                    <td>Re-Injest</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

I used ChangeDetectorRef in error of service but its also not working.

```html
[{"id":"20d2063c-58e3-4391-9971-a7c9bfd6cc66","guid":"2ABs0qlpwoZj","title":"Georgia","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906022212,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"4e409f42-177c-4b0e-a6d7-d3459d2b1a60","guid":"r9wjARFp5ybo","title":"Dead Man Walking","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906028718,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"ca279d00-3a07-48ae-8ff3-efd524060059","guid":"zIVqvJQ80lmE","title":"Taxi Driver","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906031223,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"63aca7dc-17ba-4f4f-a75a-e6667b3e03dc","guid":"OYv845bmL0yA","title":"Unforgettable","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906034716,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"5717d61c-e8dd-4e30-b02e-42c73aa56ff7","guid":"QHbHU1LRNjTQ","title":"GoldenEye","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906043909,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"555de673-88de-4911-8418-600e39253f08","guid":"A4no5EdT4i69","title":"It Takes Two","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906065093,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"b17e412e-5438-450d-8a2d-2f3414c103d5","guid":"hQ1j4MYyyFZA","title":"Sabrina","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906067911,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"4ec72565-72eb-4348-a985-b457ae5318ad","guid":"5glGh59h45IJ","title":"The American President","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906070579,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"c611ed9e-2c27-4795-8317-639037753090","guid":"MZgULmywtVQR","title":"Kids of the Round Table","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906073218,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"a36ef9f8-3154-470e-ac3e-5de68692e026","guid":"itGULjm1tWf9","title":"Across the Sea of Time","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906076013,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"fd444ae6-722d-4959-becf-34417bd0f282","guid":"Ii5YffceXL2n","title":"Don't Be a Menace to South Central While Drinking Your Juice in the Hood","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906078785,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null},{"id":"6074d7c1-a420-45dc-8418-9b3ea20e5bee","guid":"ruPJj6svK7YK","title":"White Squall","type":"MOVIE","description":null,"startTime":1557906082274,"duration":null,"status":"Completed","streamoneId":null,"published":false,"error":null}]
```

Comment: Do you examine https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started ?

Comment: what is assetsList here?

Comment: You are storing the data in jobDetails but looping over assetsList. did you missed anything?

Comment: assetsList is just the array with data to be filled in the table

Comment: can you please show the data of assetList?

Comment: @santosh sorry man but miss typed it here, no problem with that.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd added json

Comment: Perhaps the data response is not what you attached. if assetsList is an array then this.jobDetails.status will throw you an undefined error. please check the response from the api and attach it here.

Comment: @Santosh No maan, there is no issue with the api. There problem is with datatable, i do have other table's with same issue.

Comment: @V5NXT Where Do I reproduce the same issue? Can you provide stacknlitx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add `this.dtTrigger.next()` after populating data

`dtTrigger: any = new Subject();`

```
this.detailsService.getJobDetails(this.jobId).subscribe(data => {
  this.assetsList = data;
  this.dtTrigger.next();
  ...
});
```

Comment: Sorry the issue still persists

Comment: Please `Console.log(data)` and share the response

Comment: Its just an array of objects, i did add it with the qn