# Datatable not updated after add,delete or edit Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datatables

I am using a jquery datatable I have a add, edit and a delete options they work fine. However when I want to integrate the jquery datatable in my code there are some issues when I use the sort or the search it is still uses the old data. I am trying to use the approved answer that I found here [Data table is showing no data available in table using Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44940021/data-table-is-showing-no-data-available-in-table-using-angular) from stephane but I am unsure how to use it with my code.

To be more exact I am unsure where to use the

```
PopulateTable();
rerender();
```

Thank you for your help.

Here is my front end code. I have tried adding the [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" put I am unsure when to call it in my .ts file.

```
<p *ngIf="!families"><em>Loading...</em></p>


<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="display table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" width="100%"  *ngIf="families">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>{{'family.Name' | translate}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let family of families">
      <td>
        <a *ngIf="editFamilyModel.familyId  != family.familyId" [title]="family.familyId + ' family-details'" (click)="edit(content, family.familyId)" href="javascript:void(0);">
          <span class="material-icons md-18 clickable">
            edit
          </span>
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="editFamily && editFamilyModel.familyId  === family.familyId" [title]="family.familyId + ' family-details'" (click)="save(content, family.familyId)" href="javascript:void(0);">
          <span class="material-icons md-18 clickable">
            save
          </span>
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="editFamily && editFamilyModel.familyId  === family.familyId" [title]="'Cancel changes'" (click)="cancel(content, family.familyId)" href="javascript:void(0);">
          <span class="material-icons md-18 clickable">
            cancel
          </span>
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="editFamilyModel.familyId  != family.familyId" (click)="open(content, family.familyId)" href="javascript:void(0);">
          <span class="material-icons clickable">
            delete
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td *ngIf="editFamily && editFamilyModel.familyId === family.familyId">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="editFamilyModel.familyName" />
      </td>
      <td *ngIf="editFamilyModel.familyId != family.familyId">{{ family.familyName }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <span class="material-icons clickable" (click)="addFamily()">
            add_box
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input [(ngModel)]="addFamilyModel.familyName" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" (keydown.enter)='addFamily()'>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>


<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">{{ 'HtmlElement.Popup.Confirmation' | translate }}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>{{ 'family.ApproveDelete' | translate }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="d('Cross click')">{{ 'HtmlElement.Popup.Cancel' | translate }}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('yes')">{{ 'HtmlElement.Popup.Yes' | translate }}</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Here is .ts file

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDismissReasons, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { DataTableDirective, DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Family } from '../../../models/family';
import { FamilyService } from '../../../services/family.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-families',
  templateUrl: './families.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./families.component.css']
})
export class FamiliesComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  dtElement: DataTableDirective;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();


  closeResult: string;
  public families: Family[];
  public editFamilyModel: Family;
  public addFamilyModel: Family;
  public editFamily: boolean = false;


  // We use this trigger because fetching the list of persons can be quite long,
  // thus we ensure the data is fetched before rendering
  //dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();


  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private familyService: FamilyService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private readonly chRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      language: {
        url: 'assets/i18n/datatable/' + this.translate.currentLang + '.json'
      },
      //paging:false,
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      //mark: {
      //  exclude: ['td.no-marking']
      //},      
      processing: true,
      responsive: true,
      order: [[1, 'asc']],
      columnDefs: [{
        targets: [0],
        searchable: false,
        orderable: false,
        className: 'no-marking',
        width: "50px"
      }]
    };

    this.editFamilyModel = {
      familyId: 0,
      familyName: ""
    }


    this.addFamilyModel = {
      familyId: 0,
      familyName: ""
    }
    this.PopulateTable();
  }

  PopulateTable() {
    this.familyService.getFamilies().subscribe(result => {
      this.families = result;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }

  rerender(): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      // Destroy the table first
      dtInstance.destroy();
      // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
  }


  open(content, familyId: number) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' }).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
      if (result === 'yes') {
        this.deleteFamily(familyId);
      }
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  save(content, familyId: number) {

    this.familyService.updateFamily(this.editFamilyModel).subscribe(result => { 
      this.editFamily = false;
      this.editFamily = false;
      this.editFamilyModel.familyId = 0;
      this.PopulateTable();

      this.toastr.success("Success", "The family has been updated!")

    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });

  }

  edit(content, familyId: number) {
    this.editFamily = true;

    this.familyService.getFamily(familyId).subscribe(result => {
      this.editFamilyModel = result;
      this.PopulateTable();
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });

    // this.PopulateTable();
  }

  cancel() {
    this.editFamily = false;
    this.editFamilyModel.familyId = 0;

    this.toastr.info("Family modification has been cancled")
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }

  deleteFamily(familyId: number) {
    this.familyService.deleteFamily(familyId).subscribe(data => {
      if (data == null) {
        this.PopulateTable();
        this.toastr.warning("Warning", "The family has been eliminated!")
      } else {
        this.toastr.error("Error", "Something went wrong")
      }
    });
  }

  addFamily() {
    //get the value by its property
    console.log("Family: " + this.addFamilyModel.familyName);

    if (this.addFamilyModel.familyName == null || this.addFamilyModel.familyName == "") {
      //DO NOTHING
      this.toastr.warning("Warning", "The family must have a value!")
    }
    //To do check for duplicate
    else {
      this.familyService.addFamily(this.addFamilyModel).subscribe(result => { /*Can do anything here with result*/
        if (result != null) {
          this.PopulateTable();
          this.toastr.success("Success", "The family has been added!")
        }
        else {
          this.toastr.warning("Warning", "The family already exists!")
        }

      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
    }

  }

}
```

And here is the services code if you need it.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Family } from '../models/family';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FamilyService {
  public families: Family[];
  public postId: number;

  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getFamilies() {
    return this.http.get<Family[]>(this.baseUrl + 'componentFamily', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("jwt")}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      })
    });
  }

  deleteFamily(idFamily: number) {
    return this.http.delete<Family>(this.baseUrl + 'componentFamily/' + idFamily, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("jwt")}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      })
    });
  }

  addFamily(family: Family) {
    return this.http.post<Family>(this.baseUrl + 'componentFamily', family)
  }

  updateFamily(family: Family) {
    return this.http.put<Family>(this.baseUrl + 'componentFamily', family)
  }

  getFamily(familyId: number) {
    return this.http.get<Family>(this.baseUrl + 'componentFamily/' + familyId)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the services code ?

Comment: @Matthieu I have added the service code for you.